# Should I learn the research methods first?

Tags: phd, research-process

I'm going to start my PhD in 10 month time. My general area will be HCI (Human Computer Interaction). Should I read papers and look at the method used in that paper then read about that method? or should I read about most research methods in the area before I start reading any paper?

Comment: It's not like you'll ever "finish" (or almost finish) reading the papers _or_ learning methods. If things go well, you'll still be working on both of those tasks for many many many years :) I would definitely tell my students to do both of these things in parallel!

Answer (score 1):

Learning styles differ, but most people find it easier to understand a method as they see it applied. In order to grasp a solution, you need to understand what problems it is trying to solve.

I would probably start with one or more applied papers in the field. Though it's fine to jump into more detail about the methods as soon as you have questions. Really this need not be two separate activities.